# Limits with trigonometric functions without using L'Hospital Rule.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

I want to find the limits $$\lim_{x\to \pi/2} \frac{\cos x}{x-\pi/2} $$
and
$$\lim_{x\to\pi/4} \frac{\cot x - 1}{x-\pi/4} $$

and
$$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{\sin^2(\pi/4+h)-\frac{1}{2}}{h}$$
without L'Hospital's Rule.

I know the fundamental limits $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1,\quad \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos x - 1}{x} = 0 $$

#### Progress

Using $\cos x=\sin\bigg(\dfrac\pi2-x\bigg)$ I got $-1$ for the first limit.

Comment: **Hint:** $\cos x=\sin\bigg(\dfrac\pi2-x\bigg)$.

Comment: that helped, i got -1.

Comment: I added another question.

Answer (score 1):

In the first substittute $x=\pi/2+h$ so that when $x\to\pi/2,h\to0$ and similiarly for the other one and use some trigonometric identities to convert first one to sine and second to half angle.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to\dfrac\pi4}\frac{\cot x-1}{x-\dfrac\pi4}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to\dfrac\pi4}\frac{\cot x-\cot\dfrac\pi4}{x-\dfrac\pi4}\ \ \ \ (1)$$

$$(1)=-\lim_{x\to\dfrac\pi4}\frac{\sin\left(x-\dfrac\pi4\right)}{x-\dfrac\pi4}\cdot\frac1{\lim_{x\to\dfrac\pi4}\sin x\sin\dfrac\pi4}=?$$

Alternatively, $(1)=$ $$\frac{d(\cot x)}{dx}_{\text{ at }x=\dfrac\pi4}$$

---

Similarly, $$\lim_{x\to\dfrac\pi2}\frac{\cos x}{x-\dfrac\pi2}=\lim_{x\to\dfrac\pi2}\frac{\cos x-\cos\dfrac\pi2}{x-\dfrac\pi2}$$

We can use [Prosthaphaeresis Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) now